# How does android know if the wifi connection has internet access or not

Tags: android, android-intent, wifi, android-wifi

The company I work for is putting up free wifi hotspots around the town. To connect to the internet the client first has to agree to the Terms and conditions, a simple form with the terms and a button for accepting. Before they have accepted, they are not granted full internet access.

**The problem** we have is with some android devices, they no longer prompt you with this "login" form as you connect to the wifi automatically. Instead a small indicating icon shows up in the upper left corner stating that an additional signup step is required before internet access. Meanwhile the client is using the internet in the believe that they are using wifi, but in reality they are using there 3G and mobile data that costs the client money.

**The suggested fix** we came up with is to fake internet access by letter the traffic trough that the android device is using to be able to determine if they have internet or not. By doing so, the phone wont use the clients 3G net. Instead the traffic will be blocked by us until they figured out that they need to accept the terms that this little icon in there phone has indicated. It's ofc not the best solution, but it will help the clients to not receive an unexpected huge bill in the end of the month :)

**The question I have** is what traffic we need to allow for this to work? Is it just an IP that every android phone in the world is using every time they need to see if they have internet access through wifi (sounds very unlikely to me), or how does it work?

Comment: 'fake internet access by letter the traffic trough that the android device is using to be able to determine if they have internet or not.' Sorry, i do not understand a word of this. What's happening here?

Comment: Is it possible to use data over wifi is when wifi is connected regardless of whether wifi has internet connectivity or not?. As per my understanding android gives first priority to wifi over data when wifi is enabled.

Comment: @greenapps they are connected to the internet, but have restricted access until they accepted the terms. The android phone notices somehow that there is no internet access, the only way we can come with it to do so is by attempting to connect somewhere. If we allow that traffic, it will use the wifi connection for internet, and follow our restrictions until they have accepted the terms.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar You are correct, the problem described in the question is that the clients don't understand that they need to accept the terms before they have a wifi connection. So they use the 3G net. The solution to the problem, which is the huge bill they recive in the end of the month, is to grant internet access by wifi to the extent it needs to be recognize that it has internet connection through wifi. By doing so, no 3G net will be used.

Comment: a tcpdump in your wifi hotspot should help you know the traffic details. ip/tcp port/http etc...

Comment: @JiangYD Yes it will, but it won't give me the insight if it differs from device to device.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk As stated in the question, "...some android devices..." :) we also notice that it sometimes works as expected, but for does that it don't, we need this fix :)

Comment: @ErikLandvall android should use wifi even the wifi hotspot is offline, i know it because i've developed many android phone(brand Huawei). your are asking a non-standard  device, we are not able to know these all non-standard devices's internet detecting traffic, just one by one analyzing.

Comment: @JiangYD So, different devices is using different techniques to detect if the wifi it's connected to offers internet access? If the phone is using wifi, then 3G/4G should be deactivated, except in some narrow cases when the standard has been broken?

Comment: @ErikLandvall 1st question, I don't know. 2nd question, yes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question is a bit old but I want to share what I've learned about this subject when I implemented my own solution.

What you want to do is basically a **captive portal**. Android devices detect captive portals requesting a specific URL, that currently is **http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204**. If they receive a 204 response then there's connectivity. If they receive a 30x response, then there's a captive portal in the way. In that case the user is prompted with a login page from the portal where he can accept terms or provide additional information.

This happens every time the device connects to a network. Once connected it keeps checking to ensure that the network still have an available connection (I don't know to say the interval of checking, but it is a few minutes).

To debug better you should log your clients requests and see what they are trying to access when they log into your network. This is because the concept of captive portal is common and every client/platform requests its own URL.

Additionally, you could use a captive portal solution (if not using one yet). There are many out there that could accomplish what you want. Just to cite some, take a look at **Nodosplash**, **CoovaChilli** and **WiFiDog**.

Comment: I accept yours as an answer sense it's the closest you can come, but the real answer to my question was that it's a bad question :) the behavior I reported was non standard as explained by Jiang YD in the comment section to my question.

Comment: OK, I just wanna share some knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, users are asked for confirmation every time they connect.  If so, the solution would be to use something like the MAC of the telephone to identify the user and keep it in a database which is checked when a user tries to access the network.
That does leave the (very slight) possibility of duplicate MACs.  In which case new users after the first (for a given MAC) will never be asked.
Since I'm not an android programmer, I don't know how easy it would be to extract the MAC of each new user.  Don't expect it would be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for taking there time to answer, but it doesn't address the the question. The answer is in the comments, basically.. there's no answer sense it's not a standard behavior... (a bit drunnk right now, shouldn't reply, but know I will forget it else)